# Restrict documents returned by spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

A class `Dog` is using a private field `owner` to keep the owner username kept in class `User` (which implements `UserDetails`):

```
@Document
public class Dog {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String owner;
}

@Document
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private String username;

}
```

These documents are persisted using `spring-data-mongodb` and exposed using `spring-data-rest`. User is authenticated using Spring Security, so it is available as `@AuthenticationPrincipal`.

It is requested that REST can only access to the dog the user owns. Is it possible to tweak spring-data-rest to return only a subset of the documents from collection `dogs`, the ones with 'owner' field is the same as the username in the `User` instance returned by the authentication principal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did in such a scenario was implementing custom [RepositoryInvoker](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/invoke/RepositoryInvoker.html).

The invoker was a proxy for the one created by Spring Data Rest. The idea was to intercept `invokeFindAll` (or other method that should filter by the ownership) and delegate to the the query method that implements the filtering.

Note the I was using Spring Data JPA and [Specfications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) to implement the filtering predicate. I believe similar approach should by feasible with Mongo.